# How to track share events in Google Analytics 4

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

In Universal Analytics (deprecated), I was able to track share events like this:

```js
gtag('event', 'facebook', {
  'event_category': 'share',
  'event_label': 'abc123',
});
```

I could then query the number of share data like this:

```php
// endpoint: https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

...
'metrics' => [
   ['expression' => 'ga:totalEvents']
],
'dimensions' => [
   ['name' => 'ga:eventLabel'],
   ['name' => 'ga:eventAction'],
],
```

With Firebase Analytics, which is backed by Google Analytics 4, you can see their recommendation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#SHARE) which is also mirrored [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#share) with this example:

```js
gtag("event", "share", {
  method: "Twitter",
  content_type: "image",
  item_id: "abc123",
});
```

There is a new API for querying this data: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

You can see the lists of dimensions and metrics here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

- Dimensions

  - eventName
  - itemId
  - method
  - contentType
- Metrics

  - eventValue
  - eventCount

Using this new endpoint, I can't figure out how to craft a request to generate a report with event count aggregations broken down like this:

| Event Method | Item Id | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Twitter | abc123 | 6 |
| Twitter | xyz987 | 27 |
| Facebook | abc123 | 14 |

Rather, I can't seem to get the event counts by `itemId` at all.

**Edit:** it looks like an announcement [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/changelog#2022-09-13_schema_compatibility_changes_announcement) states "Item-scoped dimensions like `itemName` are becoming incompatible with event-scoped metrics like `eventCount`."

Comment: Yes you are right. The item scope can not be viewed with event scope currently. If your event parameter quota usage is very low. Then you can consider to create another event parameter to store item_id if this report is really important.